# Open / Load file with Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I have an angular 4 application and in this one, I want to open / load a svg file to have the string inside.
So I want to open a file like svg or txt and get the string corresponding.

I try to do this :

```
this.http.get('assets/images/module.svg').map(res => res.text()).subscribe(text => {this.data = text});
```

But `this.data` is always undefined whereas if I do :

```
this.http.get('assets/images/module.svg').map(res => res.text()).subscribe(text => {console.log(text)});
```

I have the string in the console.

Do you know why I can't get the string or if there is an other way to open a file ?

Comment: can you try this 
`this.http.get('assets/images/module.svg').map(res => res.text()).subscribe(text => this.data = text);` remove the curly braces

Comment: It's the same : `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying some thing like this

```
this.http.get('assets/images/module.svg').map(res => res.text()).subscribe(text => this.data = text);

console.log(this.data);
```

> The first call is a `async` call so it takes some time to get the data
>   and assign it to the variable where as the `console.log` is a `sync`
>   statement which happens immediately so you get undefined .

If you want to use the this.data i would suggest you to do all the process inside the subscribe .

eg

```
   this.http.get('assets/images/module.svg').map(res => res.text()).subscribe(text => { this.data = text; console.log(this.data));
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But how I can do if I want to use the file's content in the variable `this.data` after that ?

Comment: Because I need to open 3 files and use the content of the 3 files in the same time. So, how can I do to open the 3 files without waiting the opening of the first one then the second ?

Comment: Make use of [obserbable.forkJoin](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx/rxjs)